# Module '' is not available error in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, broccolijs

I have an AngularJS web application. Everything works fine but I've noticed this error during start up on the console log:

Basically it complains about a module not being found, a module with an empty name?

> Module '' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or
>   forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.

the exception creates automatically a URL to the online help, of course the p0 parameter is emtpy

> https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=

Inspecting further if I follow the stack trace I end up in this file here (it's very long, so for convenience I'll crop it

```
angular.module("").run(['$templateCache', function(a) { a.put('/app/components/upload/upload.html', '<et-top-nav></et-top-nav><div class="uploadPage"><div style="margin-top:3.7em"><et-uploader></et-uploader>....
```

The parameter for the module() function looks to be an empty string

The name of the app is "app", not an empty string

any clue on what's going on here?

**EDIT**

App initialization:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module("app", ["ngNewRouter", "ngSanitize", "ngFileUpload", "ngToast", "ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap"])
        .config(["$locationProvider",  configureLocationProvider])
        .config(["$httpProvider",      configureHttpProvider])
        .config(["ngToastProvider",     configureToastProvider])
        .controller("AppController", ["$router", "$rootScope", "onChartUrlChange", appController])
        .run(["onWindowResize", setup]);

    function appController($router, $rootScope, onChartUrlChange) {
        $router.config([
            { path: "/",                components: {"default":"chartPicker"} },
            { path: "/upload",          components: {"default":"upload"} },
            { path: "/batch/:groupId",  components: {"default":"chart"} }
        ]);

        // AngularJS doesn't update components on frag change, so we do it ourselves
        $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function() {
            onChartUrlChange.updateChart();
        });

        $rootScope.$on("$zoomUrlChanged", function() {
            onChartUrlChange.updateChart();
        });
    }
```

The template file generated by Broccoli doesn't include the name of the app (which sould be "app")

```
angular.module("").run(['$templateCache', function(a) { a.put('/app/components/chart-picker/chart-pi...
```

and this is causing the exception

Comment: Are you running a compile step? Are you sure your app compiled properly?

Comment: I'm using Broccoli

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialise the app

Comment: please check my edit

Comment: Brococoli compiles your `angular.module("app")` to `angular.module("")`?